# Use of UNDERSCORE in Layer Context Menu

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

Using QGIS version 3.8
I have a group of layers that I want to rename to get rid of a prefix inserted from the import process.

As I began to right-click on each, I notice an underline
[image]

I am hoping to use this, but looking in the Keyboard Shortcuts and elsewhere online, I am not finding a reference to it.

Is the indicator there for some other reason, maybe?

Comment: They are `Alt+(underlined letter)` shortcuts. They're not QGIS specific, they are/used to be fairly universal.

Comment: I am on 3.8 and on Linux (Manjaro)
Within the program I expect those to be mapped somewhere.  I looked for a Layer / Rename to remap it, but found nothing for that.  Any guidance would be helpful.  Thanx.

Comment: They are defined in code, I don't think you can remap them without patching and recompiling from source - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/layertree/qgslayertreeviewdefaultactions.cpp#L71

Comment: On Windows, selecting a layer and hitting F2 will allow you to rename it without going through the right-click menu. Maybe Linux has an equivalent hotkey.